# How to identify whether server's port is accessible?

Tags: php, html, ping, minecraft

I am trying to implement a PHP script that will ping an IP on a specific port and echo out whether the server is online / offline.  This way, users will be able to see if non-access to the server is a server fault or a own network problem.

The site is currently on http://Dev.stevehamber.com.  You can see the "Online" is wrapped in a class of 'PHP' and I need this to reflect if the server is online or offline.  The application runs on port TCP=25565 so I need the output to show if this port is reachable or not.

Here is a snippet I found that is (I suppose) what I'm looking for:

```
<?php

$host = 'www.example.com';
$up = ping($host);

// if site is up, send them to the site.
if( $up ) {
        header('Location: http://'.$host);
}
// otherwise, take them to another one of our sites and show them a descriptive message
else {
        header('Location: http://www.anothersite.com/some_message');
}

?>
```

How can I replicate something like this on my page?

Comment: And what is your question now?

Comment: I'm just looking for some guidance on how to replicate something like this on my page.  - Sorry if the above wasn't clear on this.

Comment: Do you mean "ping" (ICMP Echo) or "connect via TCP"? Neither are particularly complex, but they require very different mechanisms and the former requires either the sockets extension or the ability to `exec()`

Comment: @SteveHamber It's not about ease of application, it's about what information you actually want. Just because the server responds to ICMP echo does not mean a particular application is running on it (or even that it's the right server). What is the end game here - do you want to show that the server is up (i.e. physical box switched on) or that a specific application is up and running (as implied by `on a specific port`)?

Comment: Hi @DaveRandom as I mentioned above this is something completely new to me so my apologies for underestimating the task.  Yes, the application runs on port TCP=25565 so I need the output to show if this port is reachable or not.  Thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments on the question, [`fsockopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) is the simplest and most widely available way to accomplish this task.

```
<?php

    // Host name or IP to check
    $host = 'www.example.com';

    // Number of seconds to wait for a response from remote host
    $timeout = 2;

    // TCP port to connect to
    $port = 25565;

    // Try and connect
    if ($sock = fsockopen($host, $port, $errNo, $errStr, $timeout)) {
        // Connected successfully
        $up = TRUE;
        fclose($sock); // Drop connection immediately for tidiness
    } else {
        // Connection failed
        $up = FALSE;
    }

    // Display something    
    if ($up) {
        echo "The server at $host:$port is up and running :-D";
    } else {
        echo "I couldn't connect to the server at $host:$port within $timeout seconds :-(<br>\nThe error I got was $errNo: $errStr";
    }
```

Note that all this does is test whether the server is accepting connections on TCP:25565. It does not do anything to verify that the application listening on this port is actually the application you are looking for, or that it is functioning correctly.